# OS error: [WinError 123] seen when while un compressing a tarfile(created in linux)

Tags: python-3.x, tarfile

I have a `tarfile` in which one folder is having name `#997_Mon_Oct_14_17:12:29_CST_2013.tar`.

This file is created in a linux environment. I want to untar this file in windows env.

Using `tarfile`, if i extract i am getting  below error. Since windows dont't accept folder name with ":".

> OS error: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\Users\310190224\Desktop\test\.\lib\modules\#997_Mon_Oct_14_17:12:29_CST_2013'

Code snippet:

```
import tarfile

tar=tarfile.open("file name","r")
tar.extractall()
```

Can anyone help to override this problem.

Comment: any help is appreciated